# DolphinDB: How to use metaprogramming to resolve variables that are indirectly assigned function names?

Tags: casting, metaprogramming, dolphindb

Metaprogramming functions can resolve the variables that are assigned function names. For example:

```
s=sum
makeCall(s,[1,2,3])
```

However, metaprogramming functions cannot deal with the variables indirectly assigned, as shown in the script below:

```
s=defs('sum').name[0]
makeCall(s,[1,2,3])
Server response: 'makeCall(s, [1,2,3]) => The first argument must be a builtin or user defined fu
nction.'
```

It seems that the error is caused by data type mismatch. `s=defs('sum').name[0]` may return a STRING instead of a FUNCTIONDEF. I have tried to convert the data type using `cast(s, FUNCTIONDEF)`, but the result is not as expected. Can someone explain why the error occurs and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is right. To convert “s“ into a FUNCTIONDEF, you can use the `funcByName` function:

```
makeCall(funcByName(s),[1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseExpr` to parse your STRING function name:

```
s = "sum"
makeCall(parseExpr(s).eval(), [1,2,3])
```